# My DB file size over 700 MB Any problem?

Tags: database

I just exported my DB and found my DB file size 761 MB

I think this is too heavy and effect badly to admin performance

Am I something wrong while running store? Is it okay with this big db file size?

(I just also found I exported same commend and found my DB file size 665 MB this time strange..)

Comment: For an established store this is actually small - I regularly work on stores with databases of several GB in size.

Comment: Sounds about right. You are after all, running Magento. It's one of the reasons you don't run Magento on a resource poor server. If database size is your major concern, you need to check into other ecommerce software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely fine. You can do some cleaning of various tables without affecting the store. [Example cleanup operations](http://docs.nexcess.net/article/magento-database-maintenance.html). I've worked on sites with 3-5GB database dumps. Good sites, nice load times and no issues.

Comment: Thanks! I just dump again I got 1.7 GB, Do you know why the file size different each time I dump?

Comment: Could be logs, or some system working with a temporary table?

Answer (score 2):

Magento maintains several tables for logging. These tables log things such as customer accesses and which products have been compared. Magento has a mechanism for cleaning these logs regularly, but unfortunately this feature is disabled by default and most customers do not turn it on.you can use below SQL query to clean your DB table.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;
TRUNCATE catalog_compare_item;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: Be wary truncating `report_viewed_product_index` - it can cause catastrophic product page errors on some sites.